Decrease pdf file size
I faced a problem when converting tiff image to a pdf document using itext7, the size of the PDF doubled the size of the image and I tried many solutions but no way
find my code
private static byte[] ConvertToPDF(byte[] imgeByte, string fileExtension)
{
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream ExportFile = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ExportFile, new WriterProperties().SetPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_5)
                 .SetCompressionLevel(CompressionConstants.BEST_COMPRESSION).SetFullCompressionMode(true)))
            {
                using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer, new DocumentProperties()))
                {
                    using (Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.A4, true))
                    {
                        iText.IO.Image.ImageData imageData = null;
                        iText.Layout.Element.Image img = null;

                        bool isTIFF = fileExtension.ToLower().Contains("tif");

                        if (isTIFF)
                        {
                            int PagesCount;
                            using (Bitmap currentImg = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(imgeByte)))
                            {
                                PagesCount = currentImg.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);

                                for (int i = 1; i <= PagesCount; i++)
                                {
                                    imageData = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.CreateTiff(imgeByte, false, i, true);
                                    img = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(imageData).SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
                                    
                                    document.Add(img);

                                    if (i < PagesCount - 1)
                                    {
                                        document.Add(new iText.Layout.Element.AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
                                        //pdfDoc.AddNewPage(i+1, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.A4);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (fileExtension.ToLower().Contains("png"))
                            {
                                imageData = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.CreatePng(imgeByte);
                            }
                            else if (fileExtension.ToLower().Contains("jpg"))
                            {
                                imageData = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.CreateJpeg(imgeByte);
                            }
                            else if (fileExtension.ToLower().Contains("pdf"))
                            {
                                return imgeByte;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                using (Bitmap currentImg = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(imgeByte)))
                                {
                                    imageData = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(currentImg, null);
                                }
                            }

                            img = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(imageData)
                                .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED_ALL);

                            document.Add(img);
                        }
                        writer.Flush();
                        document.Flush();
                        pdfDoc.SetFlushUnusedObjects(true);

                        document.Close();
                        writer.Close();
                        pdfDoc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            return ExportFile.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}

More details:
PDF document size: 73.410
Tif image size: 36.930
Tif pages : 96 page


i need to Decrease PDF file size to be same image size or less.

Scaling does a lot. How much smaller could you make the image used in the PDF? Also: Do you have a Text-Layer? Do you actually need the image or could you go with a rendered OCR, for example? It depends a lot on the actual content what you can do or not.

Also, but unrelated: catch (Exception) { throw; } don't do that. That makes no sense at all. If don't handle (nor log) the Exceptions, don't catch 'em.

Last: From experience, I'd also advise to inspect prospect images' magic header instead of trusting their file extensions alone.

Can you share the tiff file to allow reproducing the issue?

It can be. You can embed oversized images that get scaled on render. It depends on how the pdf is created.

@Fildor, I want the PDF file to be the same or less image size to use to show on a website, also I can't use OCR because it's Arabic language. and thanks for your mention related catch exception :)

@mkl, sorry I can not share it, the content is sensitive and may face problems with that

The problem appears because the input TIFF image uses JPEG compression and the image in the PDF file most likely uses Flate compression. For certain type of content JPEG achieves a much better compression ratio than Flate.
Check the iText API to see if you can tell the library to use JPEG compression for the images instead of Flate. If not, you can save the current frame of currentImg  as JPEG to a memory stream and then create a JPEG image (iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.CreateJpeg) and add it to the document.

I tried that, this way decreased the PDF file to the same image size and took more process time. In my case when the client selects a document to view, I run many processes like downloading from image content FileNet p8 then converting to pdf and in some cases adding a watermark on the document after that send document stream to UI. so All this process takes a long time to complete and I don't want to add more process as decompression the image before converting or spilt tiff image to a list of jpeg images. the client will refuse all this lost time

@HithamYosri "I don't want to add more process as decompression the image before converting or spilt tiff image to a list of jpeg images. the client will refuse all this lost time" - Have you tried splitting the tiff image to a list of jpeg images? If you use code for that that does not re-encode to JPEG but actually extracts the existing JPEG, that approach may actually speed up your processes...
